# Таблица ARP и обращения к ней

Tags: verilog

Есть необходимость построить на verilog ARP таблицу и реализовать запросы к ней. Но на данный момент ума не прилож, как можно было бы сделать таблицу типа ключ-значение с IP и MAC адресами. Подскажите пожалуйста. А так же, как лучше проходить по этой таблице, так как обычный цикл for не прокатит.

Answer (score 0):

Про сами ARP таблицы не в теме. Что у вас ключем является? IP? MAC? или надо поиск в обе стороны организовывать?

Учитывая, что вопрос по verilog. Какие у вас аппаратные ресурсы? сколько элементов в таблицу можете сохранять? (теоритически бесконечно/тысячу/сто/шестнадцать)?

Вообще, первое, что на ум приходит сделать автогенерацию:

```
input  [31:0] ip;
output [63:0] mac;


reg [63:0] macs [0:63]; // 64-е ячейки с мак адресами.
reg [31:0] ips [0:63]; // 64-е ячейки с ip адресами.

genvar i

generate
for(i=0; i<64; i++) begin: gentab
    if( ips[i][31:0] ^ ip[31:0] == 0 ) begin
        mac <= macs[i]
    end        
end
endgenerate
```

Comment: писал на ходу,  verilog'ом пользуюсь редко. потому могут быть ошибки. но идея отражена верно